# e is undefined, correct syntax for a recursive handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, events, listener

How to make a correct recursive call? In this code the console says me "e is undefined".
It's a event listener for a button ul in a unordered list.

This is my code:

```
$("button#ul").on("click", function(event){
    
     var button = $(this);
        $(button).toggleClass("active");
        
        if ($(button).hasClass('active')){


    //event listener
        $(document).on("keydown", **checkExit** = function(e) {
                                            
                            if (exit(e) == true){
                                $(button).removeClass('active');
                                $(this).off("keydown");
                            }
                            **checkExit();**
                       });
    
    
    
    
    
    function exit(event){
            
    //        alert("prevKeyCode: "+prevKeyCode);
            var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
            var doubleEnter = (code == 13 && prevKeyCode == code);
            
            if (event.type == "click"){
                return true;
            }
            else if (event.type == 'keydown'){
                
                
                if (code == 27 || doubleEnter) {
                    prevKeyCode = null;
                    return true;
                }
                else if (code == 13) {
                    prevKeyCode = 13;
                }
                else {
                    prevKeyCode = code;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I think I should define outside the function checkExit...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please add https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Kindly add the `exit` function as well. That will helo to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What makes you think you need a recursive call in an event handler?

Comment: please pass the event to `checkExit(e)`  function called inside the listener function.

Comment: @Bergi: 

This is intended as a default handler (document handler) that handles the pressing of certain keys (for example, ESC) outside the specific element where the user puts text.

Comment: Is your code `$(document).on("keydown", **checkExit** = function(e) {` *inside* the `$("button#ul").on("click",` event handler?   That's not going to work.

Comment: Even if you got passed `e is undefined` - you'll *very quickly* get a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` as there's no exit clause from your keydown handler - ie it will *always* recurse

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event as a parameter when calling `checkExit` again:

```js
$(document).on("keydown", checkExit = function(e) {
  if (exit(e) == true) {
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).off("keydown"); //spegne il gestore corrente
  }
  checkExit(e);
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this gives the attended results. I want the e parameter as the result of the new pressed keyboard keys.

I want this handler actived only when you pressed the ul/ol buttons.

Comment: @the_indios Why are you calling `checkExit` anyways then?

Comment: What are the "*ul/ol buttons*"?

Comment: This gives the intended results **as the question was asked**.  You should ask a clear question that includes all the information you need, not add bits piecemeal as solutions are provided.  Your question is currently *very* unclear - eg why is there is keydown event *inside* a click handler?  Are you expecting someone to press a key *while* they are clicking?  That makes no sense.